# Как, используя plotly, построить половину heatmap(треугольник выше/ниже главное диагонали)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, визуализация, plotly, heatmap

Хочу построить интерактивный heatmap для матрицы корреляций, в ноутбуке уже работаю с plotly.
Если строить "как есть", то выходит вот такое, потому что матрица 100х100.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу построить половину матрицы. Она будет информативнее. Для этих данных с помощью matplotlib:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу понять как мне это сделать именно в plotly. Пока приходит в голову решение вручную прописать `None` для верхнего треугольника, но возможно есть какой-то параметр или функция? В документации, увы, не нашла.

**Upd**

Пока рассмотрела еще такой вариант решения: удалила данные на главной диагонали

```
df= df.drop(['id'], axis=1).corr()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.iloc[i,i] = None
    
fig = px.imshow(df)
fig.show()
```

Выглядит информативнее, но насколько такой подход правильный я не знаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Данные по ссылке](https://dropmefiles.com/VNSxr)

Comment: посмотрите документацию `numpy.tril`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html .

Answer (score 1):

Как вы уже предположили в вопросе, проще всего заполнить верхний/нижний треугольник `NaN`. Это легко делается средствами `Numpy`:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("corr.csv", index_col=0)
corr_arr = df.to_numpy()
corr_arr[np.triu_indices_from(corr_arr)] = np.nan
df_corr = pd.DataFrame(corr_arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
fig = px.imshow(df_corr)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]